# why is my tableview not being updated?

Tags: java, javafx, smack

I´m working on a chatclient using smack and javafx.
So I´ve a tableview that lists the contacts of the logged user, and it gets the statuses of the contacts in realtime, but when it´s time to update the tableview it doesn´t do it (even tough my system.out.println shows that it should have done it). The weird thing is that it only loads data the first time it loads the tableview. 
Here is my code:

```
package login;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterGroup;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

import dto.RosterDTO;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/** Controls the main application screen */
public class MainViewController {
    @FXML
    private Button logoutButton;
    @FXML
    private Label sessionLabel;

    @FXML
    private TableView<RosterDTO> rosterTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RosterDTO, String> grupoColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RosterDTO, String> usuarioColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<RosterDTO, String> estatusColumn;

    ObservableList<RosterDTO> rosterList;

    private LoginManager loginManager;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the person table
        grupoColumn
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RosterDTO, String>(
                        "grupo"));
        usuarioColumn
                .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RosterDTO, String>(
                        "usuario"));
        estatusColumn
        .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RosterDTO, String>(
                "estatus"));        
        rosterTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    }

    public void initSessionID(final LoginManager loginManager, String sessionID) {
        this.loginManager = loginManager;
        XMPPConnection connection = this.loginManager.getXmppManager().getConnection(); 
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        Presence p = roster.getPresence("testUser1");
        System.out.println("Estatus: " + p.getStatus());
        System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
        rosterList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
            RosterDTO rosterDTO = new RosterDTO();
            rosterDTO.setUsuario(r.getUser() + "/Smack");
            System.out.println("user: " + r.getUser());
            System.out.println(r.getName()); 
            System.out.println("group: " + r.getGroups());
            for (Iterator<?> i = r.getGroups().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                RosterGroup rosterObject = (RosterGroup) i.next();
                rosterDTO.setGrupo(rosterObject.getName());
            } 
            rosterList.add(rosterDTO); 
        }
        rosterTable.setItems(rosterList);
        roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {
                System.out.println("deleted: " + addresses.size());
            }

            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {
                System.out.println("updated: " + addresses.size());
            }

            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {
                System.out.println("added: " + addresses.size());
            }

            public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom()
                        + " " + presence + " " + presence.getStatus());
                System.out.println(presence.getProperty("key")); 
                rosterList.get(0).setUsuario(presence.getStatus()); 
                rosterList.get(0).setEstatus(presence.getStatus());
                //rosterTable.setUserData(rosterList);
                rosterTable.layout();
                rosterTable.setItems(rosterList);
            }
        });     

    }
}
```

Why is it loading data the 1st time but not later?
Should I use something else besides a tableview?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what doesn't work? The presenceChanged method? Did you implement usarioProperty() and estatusProperty() in RosterDTO as required by PropertyValueFactory for it to pick up changes to the model object properties?

Comment: no I didnt I managed to solve it by adding       element.setUsuario(rosterList.get(i).getUsuario()); 
      rosterList.set(i, element); so I edit the rosterlist with the method set

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to solve it by using the method "set" from my observable list
so I left my method like this:

```
public final void displayBuddyList(final TableView<RosterDTO> rosterTable) {
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();  
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
        final ObservableList<RosterDTO> rosterList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
            RosterDTO rosterDTO = new RosterDTO();
            rosterDTO.setUsuario(r.getUser() + "/Smack");
            System.out.println("user: " + r.getUser());
            System.out.println(r.getName()); 
            System.out.println("group: " + r.getGroups());
            for (Iterator<?> i = r.getGroups().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                RosterGroup rosterObject = (RosterGroup) i.next();
                rosterDTO.setGrupo(rosterObject.getName());
            } 
            rosterList.add(rosterDTO); 
        }
        rosterTable.setItems(rosterList);
        roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
            // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String>
            // addresses) {}
            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {
                System.out.println("deleted: " + addresses.size());
            }

            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {
                System.out.println("updated: " + addresses.size());
            }

            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {
                System.out.println("added: " + addresses.size());
            }

            public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                int i = 0;
                for(RosterDTO rdto : rosterList) {
                    if (rdto.getUsuario().equals(presence.getFrom())) {
                        RosterDTO element = new RosterDTO();
                        element.setEstatus("" + presence); 
                        element.setUsuario(rosterList.get(i).getUsuario()); 
                        rosterList.set(i, element);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println("ch: " + rosterList.toString());  
            }
        }); 
    }
```